# What if I can't find a set that meet the requirements for -a requirement-?

Tags: peano-axioms

For a system to be Peano's you requite 3 things:
1) First element isn't a succesor of any other element
2) "Successor" function is injective.
3) If $A \subseteq P$, First element is in $A$, and $S(A)\subseteq A \Rightarrow A=P$

But i've got a sucesor function which makes impossible to find this $A$ set.
The fucntion is $S:P\rightarrow P$.

$S(a) = -a$ with $a>0$

$S(a)=-(a-1)$ with $a<0$

$S(a)=1$ for a=0

P is the set of integers, also the first element of my system is $0\in P$ (not $1$)

Comment: I don't understand - what do you mean by "impossible to find this set $A$"? The point is that *if* $A$ is such a set, *then* $A$ is in fact all of $P$ (and in fact this is true of your example!).

Comment: I understand now! thank you.
In my first try i didn't have this doubt, so I tried to use an $A$ set, but I coulnd't prove $P\subseteq A$, can you give me a hint?

Comment: Suppose $A\subseteq P, 0\in A$, and $S(A)\subseteq A$. Do you see why $3\in A$? How about why $-4\in A$? Once you see the picture, it's an induction argument (or you can build an explicit isomorphism with $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: woah i see it now, so for any $x\in P$, there is a line of succesors which lead to $0$, which we know it's an element of $A$. Since the third requirement (called induction principle in my book) is the only thing you have for now: Can I actually use induction to prove this statement?

Comment: You can't use induction *for this $P$*, since you're trying to prove that; but presumably you already know induction *for $\mathbb{N}$.* That's what you can use.

Comment: Introducing a notation: Let $S^3(0)=S(S(S(0)))$ and so on...
so if $x=S(0)$, then $x\in A$. (for the third condition)
supose it holds for $k, x=S^k(0)$, it holds for k+1 since $S^k(0)=x\in A$.

Hence it works for any n, now we can supose $x=S^h(0)$, for an h in $\mathbb{N} $.

Comment: BUt i think the real proof there is to prove that S(a) is an integer!